# how to send message to only 1 text channel in every server

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this code:

```
  for guild in client.guilds:  # guild stands for server
        for channel in guild.channels:
            if isinstance(channel, discord.TextChannel):  # Check if channel is a text channel
                client.loop.create_task(channel.send("123"))
```

It work by sending `123` to every server's text channel. But it will send to all text channel in 1 server. How can I limit it to only send to only 1 text channel in 1 server ?

Comment: If `guild` stands for server, you wouldn't want to loop over all the channels in `guild.channels` - instead, choose one (somehow. Maybe just always the first?)

Comment: Yea I don't want to specific only one text channel because I want it to be send to every server instead of one. So i was thinking how can I only send to the first text channel of every server ?

Comment: If your current code is working, a simple way would to be to just `break` out of the inner loop once you did send once for that server.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you want to select a channel:

- If you want to use the guild's system messages channel, you can find it with guild.system_channel ([docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.system_channel)) (You will need a backup option for if no system channel is set in that guild, like looking for channel names like "general")
- If you want to randomly select a channel you can do that with `random.choice(guild.text_channels)` as `guild.text_channels` is a list ([docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.channels)).

Edit: changed `guild.channels` to `guild.text_channels` in order to prevent picking a vc or category